# codeigniter problem login through IE, Safari, Chrome?

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, web-hosting

everything works fine in localhost but i have a problem login from other browsers like safari and chrome, in firefox its ok. may be it is because of htaccess or may be other. i tried a lot searching but come to no solution. my htaccess file look like this.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

my server folder hirarchy looks like this

```
public_html
L application
  system
  css
  images
  .htaccess
```

application/config/config.php looks like this

```
$config['index_page'] = "index.php?";
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'QUERY_STRING';
```

i have used hmvc too.
any help?

Comment: whats all this code have to do with your login/form/process? Need more code or something here... or do you want us to guess?

Comment: it works fine on localhost. it means it may be the problem of htaccess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you updated the base_url variable in your config file to reflect the new server?

Comment: i don't think without updating the base_url the site will be running.

Comment: It depends on how your site is set up. I have encountered issues in the past with the same symptoms that were caused by this.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue. What I found is the Native session class solution which helped me to overcome with the same problem. Take a look at CI Native session. This will also works with all major browsers.
http://codeigniter.com/wiki/Native_session/